Movie about a teen who forms a bond with and looks after a baby boy
Saw a movie in the 80s or 90s set in Mexico, Central or South America (English subtitles) about a teenage boy--run away or orphan--who is taken in by a young couple with a baby boy. The infant and teen immediately take to one another so the teen is often left to babysit while the parents work. They grow so close that the teen becomes the only one who can comfort the child when he cries. Since the baby's dad is rarely home, and when he is home he's verbally or physically abusive to his mom, the baby starts to view the teen his dad.
During one of the parents' fights, the mother gives the teen this "look" as if to say save my child, so the boy leaves with the boy. As they're leaving the mother can be heard screaming while she's being beaten by the dad.
The rest of the movie centers around the boy and child as he makes his way throughout the city, staying with various friends--who all develop a fondness for the baby and help take care of him. In the end, the teen goes out with some friends, after leaving the baby with a girl friend. Unbeknownst to the teen at the time, the friends decide to rob someone. As they ran off he is left bewildered, wondering what happened. Since he was with them the police assumes he was in on the robbery and starts shooting at him. As expected, he runs and is shot in the back. It is not shown if he survives.
